# JavaScript translates my "a" string to &#x27;a&#x27;

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm sending:

```
short_names = ["a", "b"]
```

as context through function view to JS.

Then I'm using it in JS:

```
let names = {{ short_names }};
```

But what i really got is:

```
labels: [&#x27;a&#x27;, &#x27;b&#x27;]
```

What's going on with this behaviour? How may omit it?

Comment: Are the double brackets `{{ ... }}` right? In JavaScript not, about Python, Django I don't no anything.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's django templates proper bracket. It works fine for integer, but doesn't for strings.

Comment: How are you sending? In python, the string representation of short_names is `"['a', 'b']"` which looks what you got on the other end. If you did `str(shrot_names)` to send instead of say, a json encoding, that would explain it.

Comment: Those are html entities for single quotes

Comment: For instance, `html.escape(str(["a", "b"]))` gives you the string you see: `[&#x27;a&#x27;, &#x27;b&#x27;]`

Comment: @tdelaney is there a way to do this in second direction `[&#x27;a&#x27;, &#x27;b&#x27;]` to `["a", "b"]`?

Comment: Django will escape HTML until [instructed otherwise](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape).

Comment: I think that `short_name = json.loads(["a", "b"])` is what you want.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, now I get it.

Answer (score 8):

Convert your context variable to JSON with `json.dumps` then in the javascript

```js
let variable = {{ context_variable|safe }};
```